# Cookies & URL's and instances

Tags: javascript, cookies, webserver

I've got a Web App that sets a cookie in it's Javascript code which subsequently gets sent to the server on all HTTP GET requests. If I open a new Tab in Chrome and access a different page on the same server the server is seeing the cookie set in the Web Apps JS code, even though the Javascript code on this new page doesn't set any cookie. What gets weirder is I can close all Browser Tabs that are open on the site and open a new one on a non-existent 404 page and I continue to see a cookie set both when I look at the server request and in the Browser using EditThisCookie.

I don't understand why I'm seeing cookies on pages other than the Web App's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are built to behave in these manners. While defining cookies, expiry time is also set with that. With each request the cookie is sent to the server until it is expired for that domain.
If you wish that your cookie not to sent on next browser session, you should create non-persistent cookies.
Note that cookies can be created/deleted both from client(via javascript) and server side.
You can find below link helpful.
http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/2010/09/ClientSideStorage.html
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't set an expiry date which means the cookie is non-persistent and I would have thought closing the only Tab accessing the site would then forget the cookie, but it doesn't. I can and have no choice but to live with this behaviour but it seems odd to me.